# How to convert MAC address into IPv6 link local address and vice-versa

Tags: php, networking, ipv6

It is often helpful to convert IPv6 link local addresses (e.g. from a broadcast ping) into a mac address. Converting a known mac-address into a fe80::-IPv6-address is also useful to connect to a specific device with a known physical address.

How can I (in PHP) convert a string with a MAC address into a fe80-Link local address and vice-versa?

Comment: It is not required for the link-local address to follow modified EUI-64 format. In this case there is no relation between IPv6 address and MAC address.

Answer (score 1):

The required algorithm is specified in RFC4291, appendix A.
https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4291#appendix-A

Here's an example implementation in PHP:

```
/**
 * Converts a MAC-Address into the fe80:: IPv6 link local equivalent
 * 
 * @param string $mac MAC-Address 
 */
function macTov6LL(string $mac)
{
    $mac = preg_replace('/[^a-f0-9]/', '', strtolower($mac));

    $ll = substr($mac, 0, 1);
    $ll .= dechex(hexdec(substr($mac, 1, 1)) ^ 2);
    $ll .= substr($mac, 2, 4);
    $ll .= "fffe"; 
    $ll .= substr($mac, 6, 6); 
    $ll = wordwrap($ll, 4, ":", true); 

    return inet_ntop(inet_pton("fe80::" . $ll));
}

/**
 * Converts a fe80:: IPv6 Link Local Address into a MAC-Address
 * 
 * @param string $ipv6ll fe80:: Link Local Address 
 */
function v6LLToMac(string $ipv6ll)
{
    $ll = unpack("H*hex", inet_pton($ipv6ll))['hex'];

    $mac = substr($ll, 16, 1);
    $mac .= dechex(hexdec(substr($ll, 17, 1)) ^ 2);
    $mac .= substr($ll, 18, 4);
    $mac .= substr($ll, 26, 6); 

    return wordwrap($mac, 2, ":", true); ; 
}

var_dump(macTov6LL("B8:27:EB:B9:E9:35"));
// results in: string(25) "fe80::ba27:ebff:feb9:e935"

var_dump(v6LLToMac("fe80::ba27:ebff:feb9:e935"));
// results in: string(17) "b8:27:eb:b9:e9:35"
```

Comment: Please be aware that RFC4291 is not used anymore in recent operating systems (at least not by default). The `v6LLToMac` function should check whether the LL address has `..ff:fe..` in the middle of the IID and otherwise report there is no embedded MAC address found.